# GNUPLOT, How can i know the coordinate (x,y,z)

Tags: graph, 3d, coordinates, gnuplot

I'm new for the Gnuplot.

I have some trouble.
For the 2D graph, There is the coordinate (x,y) at the left-bottom but i want to know.
How can i know the coordinate (x,y,z) when i move the mouse pointer on the 3D graph.
I waste my time for search the answer but I'm still cannot find.

thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible, because `gnuplot` doesn't hold all data points to be accessed by the mouse.

In 2D, the displayed coordinates are extracted from the graph boundaries, but there is no such things to snap the mouse pointer to the nearest plotted data point (like requested in [How can I make gnuplot show coordinates of a plotted function which have same x value as the mouse pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14615021/2604213)).

Because of the missing "data snapping", it is not possible to extract the 3D coordinates from the 2D mouse position.

Comment: thanks for ur answer.I wonder that there is a program can plot 3D graph and know the coordinate when i move the mouse pointer on the graph.because this function is very important for my program.